# Error when running unit test

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I have this part of code in my indexController:

```
public function init()
{
  $this->_translate = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap')->getResource('translate');
}
```

This works all fine and in PRD i don't get any errors

But when i am running my unit tests it generates the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   getResource() on a non-object in
>   K:\stage
>   5\application\controllers\IndexController.php
>   on line 9

This is my testcode:

```
class IndexControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase
{
    public function testCanDisplayOurHomepage()
    {
        //Go to the main page of the webapplication
        $this->dispatch('/');

        //check if we don't end up in an error controller
        $this->assertNotController('error');
        $this->assertNotAction('error');

        //Ok no error lets check if we are on the home page
        $this->assertModule('default');
        $this->assertController('index');
        $this->assertAction('index');
        $this->assertResponseCode(200);


    }
}
```

Comment: Please let me know the class for getResource and class of $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap').

Answer (score 3):

This was not working in my unit tests because I was only calling the application bootstrap and not then calling run.

```
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap();
```

To fix the problem I added this to the phpunit boostrap

```
$appBootstrap = $application->getBootstrap();
$front   = $appBootstrap->getResource('FrontController');
$front->setParam('bootstrap', $appBootstrap);
```

and now `$bootstrap = $this->getInvokeArg('bootstrap');` works fine in PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the bootstrap for translate in your Bootstrap call?

```
$this->bootstrap("translate")
```